# Change where php downloads files to

Tags: php, file-upload, permissions, temp

I'm trying to make an upload module on my website, but I'm getting the following error:

> PHP Warning:  Unknown: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(C:\Windows\TEMP) is not within the allowed path(s): (E:\Domains\medisearch.com.br) in Unknown on line 0
>   PHP Warning:  File upload error - unable to create a temporary file in Unknown on line 0

Comment: Show some code please, we cannot read your mind and see what you see...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

uploading files is a dangerous thing. that's why there are restrictions in php to contain the danger. one of those restrictions is the "open_basedir" directive: it limits where php may read files (e.g. to include or require) and write files (e.g. to upload).

It's a good idea to save the uploaded files in a place that is outside of the normal webspace, but then you have to add the upload directory to open_basedir, like so:

See the manual at

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir

if you get this right, there are still about 100 things that might go wrong when uploading files, things that open up a vulnerability in your app.  Read a lot about security + php before you attempt to do this!

Comment: I will most likely pay someone to do that for me, I just need a temporary solution to trusted-people only uploads, thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

There's a php.ini setting, [`upload_tmp_dir`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-tmp-dir) which controls that directory. You must change it at the php.ini level. Doing it via `ini_set()` within your script will not work - the upload will have been aborted long before your script ever starts executing.

Answer (score 1):

You cant do this on you php script, but if you have access to php.ini then you can change [upload_tmp_dir](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-tmp-dir)
 from there. You cannot change this in php because it is PHP_INI_SYSTEM directive

Answer (score 0):

Open up php.ini and search for "upload_tmp_dir"

Change this to the new location